# How to organize model classes and related database data for geographical spaces?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, data-structures

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 and MySQL. I would like to "abstract" and "handle" *geographical* spaces in a balanced way, but I am in trouble when I have to "invent" the overall structure. So...

*How to organize model classes and related database data for geographical spaces?* That is, for example, which "type" of classes should I implement - should I use something like RoR Single Table Inheritance or Polymorphic classes? - ? and, given the mentioned model class (or model classes), which table columns should I add to my database and how should those be populated in order to be retrievable (reasons for this are that I am thinking to implement a search form in order to find records in an user friendly way, perhaps with a "autocompletable name" input field)?

---

*Note*: At this time, I am planning to "organize" a geographical space in ("nested" spaces) `continents` > `countries` > `regions` > `cities` > `addresses`. However, since retrievability for search form use cases, I am wondering to create *one* only database table in order to handle those space objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think that using belongs_to and has_many would be friendly enough, even for autocompletes and something else.

```
class Continent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :countries
end 

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :continent
    has_many :regions
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :country
    has_many :cities
end
```

Something like that.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on how you'd state classes and handle data?

Comment: Added in answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I would like to store all data in *one* database table.

Comment: I don't recommend you to store all these data in only one single table, it can be messy for you or somebody to maintain in the future.